# How to remove the unknown intervention from the signal (Octave)?

Tags: noise, filtering, octave

we have a signal recording and there are always interventions, I think it is not a noise, since it is not continuous but occurs in intervals, with 25 Hz (please see below). It is not affected by the sampling rate, and the internal frequency  is near 1000 Hz.
I used median filter, Butterworth filter, and moving averages filter to filter it out. I am to a degree successful but when we increase the degree of the filter we lose our data which is important for us. I use Octave for data evaluation. Has anybody had a similar experience? Or how can I remove the intervention without damaging the original signal?
Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: Hello Seth and welcome to Signal Processing SE. I believe you should provide some more information on the problem. Maybe you could add some info on how and/or what the acquired signal(s) is(are), sampling rates, bandwidth of interest and frequency range of "interventions" and anything else you would use to reach an educated solution to your problem. This way other people here will be able to gather enough information to suggest solutions to your problem.

Comment: By far your best choice is to root cause the source of the contamination and eliminate it there.  Trying to fix this is signal processing will be difficult and the results will be fairly poor. If you can't eliminate it at the source, you need to learn as much as possible about the properties variability of the contamination so you can optimize the clean up algorithm. But this also requires root causing and understanding the physics behind the problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your problem is, mostly, spurious noise that comes out as peaks of varying degrees of sharpness. One of the simplest methods would be to calculate the derivative and, when it goes above or below a certain threshold, discard the data. Some peaks will still be there but a mild lowpass should be able to smooth them out.

I've made a mock test with Octave, so take it with a grain of salt:

```
 # time vector
t = [0:999];
 # initial signal
x = (t > 222).*sin(2*pi*t/666 - 2*pi/3).*exp(-(t - 350).^2/99999);
 # concoct random spikes of various amplitudes
r = rand(1, 996);
tmp = (r>0.52 & r<0.53).*rand(1, 996);
 # make them appear 3 times in a row with random signs
n = n=([0 0 tmp 0 0]+[tmp 0 0 0 0]+[0 0 0 0 tmp]).*(-1).^(rand(1,1000)>0.5);
 # some "generic" noise
z = rand(1, 1000)/3;
 # sum them up to give the input signal
s = x + n + z;
 # calculate the derivative
d = diff(s);
 # determine where the peaks>abs(threshold), then integrate
y = cumsum(d.*(abs(d) < 0.35));
plot(s, "", y + 1.5)
```

[image: quick spike filter]

It's not perfect, because of the spikes that need to be filtered are close to the actual noise, the threshold (here a tweaked `0.35`) will "eat up" too much, leaving hiccups, like the one you see around sample `340`. OTOH, that spike could be omitted and simply filtered to the final version (top trace, after a basic 5 points moving average).

This will not work very well if the occurence of the spikes is close to the period, or the variation of the signal, itself. In that case you need to perform the equivalent of phase unwrapping: calculate, sample by sample, the derivative, and as soon as it goes above/below the threshold, discard the data; then integrate. But it looks like your spikes stand out fairly well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried the 2. derivatives to check the 'acceleration'. But it is unfortunately so interbedded that it makes it impossible to differentiate the intervention from the actual signal.

Comment: @Seth This is not specified in your question, and should have been. What do you mean by "interbedded"? Please note I am not talking about any acceleration, I'm talking about spikes removal, which is what your question is about, as it is currently written.